# How to make the key 'WIN' used for key bindings?

Tags: keyboard, windows

I know there is a method in windows to ban the WIN key(To edit the register), and when I hit the WIN key, nothing happens.

However, can I use the key for key-bindings?

Comment: What about the FAIL key?

Comment: I stumbled upon this and now that I look at the timestamp I realize I'm incredibly late to the party but...what on earth does this have to do with gaming?

Comment: @Shinrai It doesn't have anything to do with gaming, so it should have been closed as off-topic years ago.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is about general PC/keyboard support and not gaming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a computer-related question not specific to video games. Please see this Super User post for a possible solution to your issue: [How can I disable or reassign the 'Windows' key?](https://superuser.com/q/1384/10259)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [a utility](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/map-any-key-to-any-key-on-windows-xp-vista/) to rebind keys to other keys, or [manually hack](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/) your registry to do so.  Here's [the source MSKB](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/w2kscan-map.mspx) article that they used.

For instance, the following registry key will swap `F11` and `LWIN`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,57,00,5b,e0,5b,e0,57,00,\
  00,00,00,00
```

Broken down:

- `00,00,00,00,`: Version (0)
- `00,00,00,00,`: Flags (0)
- `03,00,00,00,`: Number of entries, including trailing null (3)
- `57,00,5b,e0,`: The left Windows Key (`E0 5B`, it's backwards) is interpreted as an F11 (`00 57`)
- `5b,e0,57,00,`: F11 (`00 57`) is interpreted as the left Windows Key (`E0 5B`)
- `00,00,00,00` : Null ("we're done")

After modifying your registry, you must relog (or restart) in order for the changes to take effect.

What scancode is what key?  See [this WHDC article](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/scancode.mspx), specifically the Word document in it.  Use the values from the "scan 1 make" column.  Alternatively, some "keyboard test" utilities will tell you.

Once you've remapped keys in windows, you can bind them as you see fit.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) — no registry hacking required.

Comment: +1 for a good application I used a lot on PC (now on a Mac and miss its simplicity)